# Public computers open to all employees in our inhouse library - Need to register the downloads

Tags: windows-7, router, guest-account

Users login with a guest account, in fact it's an auto login, anyone can use these computers in our in-house library.

I've been asked by security to log what they download, but also since it's auto-login account on a standalone network not on a domain, we can't track who's used the computer so I need to create an IT register and also to track what users download.

These are Windows 7 guest accounts. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: If any one can log in and there is nothing to identify them, then the only suggestion is to go back to security and say "no"

Comment: Even if you knew what was downloaded, what difference does it make, because you don't know **who** downloaded it

Comment: and to be honest, to further @Jobbo's comment, you should already have rules in place to ensure that what is downloadable is desired in your library (ie, no inappropriate material)